# PHP OOP Cannot Query mysqli

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have been struggling for days to figure how to follow OOP in the following procedure.

Here is my connection class which handles my connection to the database.

```
<?php
class Connection{
    public $con = null;
    public function __construct(){
        return $this->con = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root", "tester");
    }

}
?>
```

And here is my Helpers Class, this class contains all the common methods that will be used in my webapp like Insert data , delete and update.

```
<?php 
class Helpers{
    public $con = null;
    public function __construct($connection){
        $this->con = $connection;
    }

    public function register($name){
        $con = $this->con;
        $sql = "insert into name(Name)value($name);";
        $con->query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Now I call them like this in my register.php

```
<?php
require "Connection.php";
require "Helpers.php";

$connection = new Connection();
$Helpers = new Helpers($connection);

$Helpers->register("Keannu");
?>
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Call to undefined method Connection::query().

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Since you're wrapping it twice, you'll have to use `$this->con->con->query()` then. Avoid the extra wrapper. And investigate PDO instead of mysqli. That's going to be less effort in the end (in particular for simpler parameter binding).

Comment: You are doing a double wrap so its going to be `con->con`. You should rethink your structure. Imo

Comment: @mario

Okay now the error is gone but it is not added on my database.

Comment: check for errors. the syntax error is clear in the value; it's a string. checking for errors is part of coding/debugging, which you're not doing

Comment: Print mysqli_errors to know what DB is returning

Comment: can one you guys give me a sample code like mine but in the correct way? . Because i'm kinda confused. :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php use that on the query

Comment: Okay thank you fred . reading it right now :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Still no good .... can you provide a code like mine but in the correct way? cause i'm confused of everything right now :( .

Comment: And guys which is better Mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: see the guy's answer below, which unfortunately, still contains a syntax error but they're not listening to me, or have left for the day.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Yea i noticed that. what should be the data type? i was thinking a string because my data type on my db is varchar.

Comment: `varchar` is correct but the answer below failed to point out about the  [string literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) from the get go, nor have they mentioned anything about checking for errors. incomplete answer far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the already given answer, strings in values need to be wrapped in quotes.

I.e.: `value ('$name');";` or `value ('".$name."');";` which is another method.

Sidenote: `value` and `values` are accepted and are both considered as valid syntax in MySQL.

As per the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
```

- For more information on string literals, visit
  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html
- Checking for errors in the query also would have signaled the syntax error.
  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Answer (score -1):

Change your class as follows. Since you are passing a Connection Object you need to set its con property to the `$this->con`.

```
<?php 
class Helpers{
    public $con = null;
    public function __construct($connection){
        $this->con = $connection->con;
    }

    public function register($name){
        $con = $this->con;
        $sql = "insert into name (Name) values ($name);";
        $con->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will still cause a syntax error during the insert `value($name)`

Comment: Look `$Helpers->register("Keannu");` <= it's a "string" ^

Comment: Should it not be a string? what data type should i use ?

Comment: @KeannuAlforqueAtilano A string should be fine to use it needs to be encapsulated in quotes though so this answer has an error. It should be `$sql = "insert into name (Name) values ('$name');";`.

Comment: @chris85 true, but Yasitha should have been the one to point that out and have been told about it. They probably left or are ignoring the comments or don't know how [string literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) work.

Comment: Okay it works now guys! THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR THE HELP ! :D P.S im new in this site xD sorry for the annoyance.

Comment: @KeannuAlforqueAtilano great and you're welcome, however I sure hope you're not going to accept it; not in its present form anyway. I wouldn't. Not till they fix the syntax error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe you should provide your kind help as an answer, and the OP should accept :)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes fred i'm gonna recode it now i know the concept . the double wrap and the string literals .Thank you very much guys, saved me from days of struggle.